# count the total of unique numbers occur in a range of cells

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hello this is my data sample

```
  coustmer_NO  id    
    1            5         
    1            13    
    2            4     
    2            4            
    2            4    
    3            4                
    3            10
    4            8
    4            8
```

using SQL >> I Would like to count for each customer how many different ID They have.
the expected output is:

```
  coustmer_NO  total_id    
    1            2         
    2            1    
    3            2     
    4            1
```

Comment: is in mysql dea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is a typo in your data,

The result should be:

```
coustmer_NO  total_id    
      1          2         
      2          1    
      3          2     
      4          1
```

You can do the following:

`SELECT costumer_NO, count(distinct id) AS total_id FROM <table_name> GROUP BY costumer_NO;`

Comment: Correct I make typo mistake first time, I wrote same as you :D:D +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query in MYSQL:

```
select coustmer_NO, count(distinct id) as 'total_id' from table_name group by coustmer_NO;
```

Comment: count(id) > counts the total number of ID.  what i want to count the unique values. kindly look again at customer 2 and 4.

Comment: Wrong query try this

Comment: Check mine and which is same as yours:D:DD: